# Автоматический повтор вопроса Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начала писать код, он работает. Но мне нужно, чтобы программа получала ответ "Yes" или "No". Если ей ответить что-либо другое, она должна повторить вопрос заново, и так до тех пор, пока не получит ответ "Yes" или "No".

Вот как выглядит код:

```
print ("Hey there! What's your name?")
name = input("")
print("Hello,",name, "Welcome to our new room!")
print ("How old are you?")
age = int(input(""))
days = age*365
minutes = age*525948
seconds = age*31556926

Join1 = input("Would you like to know how many days have you been living? ").lower()
if Join1.lower() == "yes":
  while True:
    print("Great! Let's do it. Give me a sec...")
    print("You have been living on Earth for", days, "days now, WOW! That's cool!")
    break
elif Join1.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay... maybe later. Bye.")
    exit()
else:
    print("You do not understand me.. I need Yes or No answer here.")
    
Join2 = input("And would you like to know how many minutes have you been living? ").lower()
if Join2.lower() == "yes":
  while True:
    print("Woa! I like your enthusiasm, let's do it. Give me a sec...")
    print("You have been living for", minutes, "minutes now. That's a lot!")
    break
elif Join2.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay... maybe later. Bye.")
    exit()
else:
    print("You do not understand me.. I need Yes or No answer here.")
    
Join3 = input("And what about seconds? ").lower()
if Join3.lower() == "yes":
  while True:
    print("Cool! Give me a sec...")
    print("You have been living for", seconds, "seconds now. That's really a lot!")
    print("Okay, I've run out... see you later, buddy! Have a good day.")
    break
if Join3.lower() == "no":
    print("Okay... maybe later. Bye.")
    exit()
```

После `else` повторяла вопрос еще раз, он его повторял, да. Но, насколько знаю, программа автоматически может повторять вопрос через цикл `while` бесконечное кол-во раз, пока не получит нужный ответ (в данном случае Yes/No). Только вот мне не удалось разобраться, как именно это сделать... подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Фактически дубликат удаленного вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1187151 . При чем там уже был ответ.

Comment: сайт показывал, что вопрос скрыт, поэтому повторила его. Почему его повторила - программа так же продолжала задавать новый вопрос, а не повторять первый...

Comment: @Maria Neklyudova вам мой ответ помог или нет?

Comment: @MariaNeklyudova вопрос скрыт, потому что вы удалили его, возможно случайно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    Join1 = input("Would you like to know how many days have you been living?") 
    if Join1.lower() == "yes":
        print("Great! Let's do it. Give me a sec...")
        print("You have been living on Earth for", days, "days now, WOW! That's cool!")
        break
    elif Join1.lower() == "no":
        print("Okay... maybe later. Bye.")
        exit()
    else:
        print("You do not understand me.. I need Yes or No answer here.")
```